# Woocommerce Payments and App Not Syncing

Tags: plugins

I have recently added woocommerce payments to my shop and the customers are able to select this form of payment rather than paypal. My issue is that the transactions nor the payments are appearing in my stripe app which is linked with my woocommerce. The only way I can keep track of anything is signing into my dashboard. What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure all that all stripe data is correct, even a single character could create problems, also check if you are in sandbox mode.